# SD Card doesn't boot to Noobs

Tags: sd-card, noobs

I have a raspberry Pi 3, and I bought a kit online which contained an SD card for my Raspberry Pi already, and I used it and it worked fine, though it was a fake brand, my only complaint was the low storage space, so I used my phone's SD card ( A strontium 16 Gb), and formatted it and copied NOOBS to it but it doesn't recognize the card, and no green lights are blinking, and doesn't open in the NOOBS operating selection menu.

Comment: We need more information to direct you better.
What program did you use to format your card, what file system, and did you follow any guides?

Answer (score 1):

You need to check which lights are blinking and which are not and find your case here:
http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting

Comment: It's clearly stated in the question that "no green lights are blinking".

Comment: Just to clarify the link [RishabhN](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/49498/68921) provided has [troubleshooting steps](http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Red_power_LED_is_on.2C_green_LED_does_not_flash.2C_nothing_on_display) for when the red light is on but the green light does not flash & there is nothing on the display.